# Clojure editor/IDE recommendations on Mac OS X

Tags: macos, ide, editor, clojure

I am starting to learn the [Clojure](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Clojure) programming language. Are there any recommendations for Clojure editors/IDEs on Mac OS X?

**Update 2009-09-23**: The Clojure space has changed tremendously since I originally posted this question. Many of the links below, especially those that refer to clojure-mode with Emacs, are out-of-date. The best Clojure IDE I found was the [Enclojure](http://www.enclojure.org/) Netbeans plugin which was recently released (2009-08-25).

**Update 2010-04-30**: Another very good article on this subject is *[Clojure IDEs - The Grand Tour](http://www.bestinclass.dk/index.php/2010/03/clojure-ides-the-grand-tour-getting-started/)* by Lau B. Jensen. Also, for my own clojure development, I have actually moved to Emacs / [swank-clojure](http://github.com/technomancy/swank-clojure).

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You can try [NetBeans](http://netbeans.org) with [Enclojure](http://enclojure.wikispaces.com).

Comment: Played around with Enclojure and it's a decent environment I really like it.

Comment: They need to get windows support.

Answer (score 20):

For setting up Aquamacs, Slime and Clojure, there's a screencast on [lispcast.com](http://www.lispcast.com/drupal/):

http://www.lispcast.com/drupal/node/79 (broken link)

**Edit:**
That's a nice [alternate screencast](http://paulbarry.com/articles/2008/07/02/getting-started-with-clojure-and-aquamacs) you found Jman. I've added it to my answer so it's a bit more comprehensive.

Comment: And the best thing about Aquamacs/Emacs is, once you get past the first couple of weeks of learning a new editor, you'll have gained a power tool you can use for just about anything.

Comment: Emacs is the original IDE. I've tried them all, and haven't yet found one that can do something Emacs can't. Conversely, all of them lack features that Emacs has. For any coding, and particularly for Lisp coding, it can't be beat.

And on the off chance you find a feature lacking in Emacs, it's really a Lisp runtime that happens to come with a lot of pre-written code for text editing, so you can add it fairly easily.

Answer (score 16):

Emacs+SLIME is going to be the most productive if you are going to be spending your time editing Lisp code and not doing much Java.

Paredit is also a must-have since it makes it almost difficult to insert invalid s-expressions. It takes a bit of getting used to, but it is emphatically worth it.

Answer (score 13):

One of the "big 3" Java development IDEs is IntelliJ IDEA. It used to get less market share because it's not free as in beer. JetBrains is now providing a Community Edition of [IntelliJ IDEA](http://www.jetbrains.com/idea/) . I'm not a regular Mac user myself, but the [OS X 'I use this' folks](http://osx.iusethis.com/app/intellijidea) say it runs there too.

IDEA has a plugin called **[La Clojure](http://plugins.intellij.net/plugin/?id=4050)**, available directly from the plugin manager under "Settings," that makes Clojure development pleasant and productive.

Previously, I tried

- [WaterFront](http://sourceforge.net/projects/waterfront/files/), for which "IDE" is IMO a bit of a reach;
- [Counterclockwise](http://code.google.com/p/counterclockwise/), a pretty good Eclipse plugin; and
- [Enclojure](http://www.enclojure.org/), the NetBeans plugin.

but anticipate staying with IDEA and La Clojure

Comment: +1. Have loved IntelliJ IDEA for ever. Clojure support is great.

Comment: The Community Edition also supports the La Clojure Plugin and is free and Open Source (Apache 2.0 license). And it works great :-)

Comment: I would recommend [Cursive](https://cursiveclojure.com/) over La Clojure. It has a much more useable REPL, is better at static code analysis, and has some other nice features like structural editing.

Answer (score 9):

Rich Hickey uses [Aquamacs](http://aquamacs.org/) in all of his demos.  He has commented about this, saying that he switched to it after someone created a Clojure mode for Emacs.  I have also created a [Clojure mode for jEdit](http://github.com/djspiewak/jedit-modes/tree/master/clojure.xml).

At the moment, tool support for Clojure is pretty limited.  I think you're either stuck with some Emacs variant or [jEdit](http://jedit.org).

Answer (score 5):

If you go the emacs route, I highly recommend using clojure-paredit.  [Paredit](http://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/ParEdit) takes some getting used to, but it really reinforces the "code is data" notion.

Answer (score 5):

This is an old question, but the landscape of the Clojure tooling has evolved quite a bit.

Nowadays the options are :

- [Light table](http://lighttable.com/), very easy to get started.
- IntelliJ + [Cursive](https://cursive-ide.com/) or [La Clojure](https://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/?id=4050). Someone once recommended me Cursive.
- vim + [fireplace](https://github.com/tpope/vim-fireplace). I know some very productive people use it.
- Emacs + [CIDER](https://github.com/clojure-emacs/cider) and [Paredit](http://danmidwood.com/content/2014/11/21/animated-paredit.html), my personal choice. Apparently Rich Hickey uses [Aquamacs](http://aquamacs.org/).

I personally learnt to use Emacs to use it with Clojure, although some may argue that learning two things at the same time is not a good idea.

There is a survey [here](http://blog.cognitect.com/blog/2016/1/28/state-of-clojure-2015-survey-results) regarding the popularity of IDE/Editors :

[image: survey result]

[Emacs rocks !](http://emacsrocks.com/)

Answer (score 4):

Emacs with [Slime](http://common-lisp.net/project/slime/) may be a good choice. See this [article](http://bc.tech.coop/blog/081023.html) that explains a setup.

Answer (score 3):

Emacs Carbon with SLIME and clojure-mode works like a charm. I tried Aquamacs before and it feels too different from the command line emacs for me. I really don't like Terminal.app and after months fighting against it I decided to migrate to Carbon.

Answer (score 2):

TextMate is a great editor and has a Lisp bundle, which will suffice for Clojure (there's also an in-progress bundle available [here](http://www.loufranco.com/blog/assets/clojure.zip)). I've always used TextMate + the Lisp bundle for writing Clojure code.

Answer (score 2):

I'm using Vim for Clojure and am enjoying it. I installed the Vim Clojure plugin mentioned in [the wiki](http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Clojure_Programming) and also followed the instructions there for making the REPL more user friendly using [rlwrap](http://utopia.knoware.nl/~hlub/rlwrap/).

Answer (score 2):

[Light Table](http://www.lighttable.com/) is pretty great; unfortunately I can't run it on my Mac because I'm stuck on OS X 10.6 and it requires 10.7+.

I've been using Light Table on another Mac and on several Windows computers – it's pretty nice.

[I used to help out with the open source project.]

Answer (score 1):

Bill Clementson has [updated](http://bc.tech.coop/blog/081205.html) his setup.

Answer (score 1):

You may also try IntellliJ IDEA with La Clojure plugin.

Comment: This answer is duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/257333/clojure-editor-ide-recommendations-on-os-x/1699579#1699579

Answer (score 0):

I use Clojure on MacOSX for about 3 months. I am very happy with Emacs and use it for more an more tasks. The start was quite hard but now i would say it was worth the efforts to learn emacs.
For IntelliJ 10 the La Clojure Plugin has been updated so that it should work now with Clojure 1.2.0 again.